# Ontology not getting data from imported ontology

Tags: owl-api

I have an ontology and I use the OWL API to import another ontology,

```
OWLImportsDeclaration importDeclaraton = Factory.getOWLImportsDeclaration(IRI.create("file:/path/to/ontology.owl"));

ontology.getOWLOntologyManager().applyChange(new AddImport(ontology, importDeclaraton));
```

The new ontology contain some abox assertions in it, however, when I query the ontology for its abox axioms, there is nothing in it.

```
System.out.println(ontology.getABoxAxioms(true));
```

returns []

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the OWL API does not seem to load imports on the fly, i.e., when a new import is added programmatically - it will attach the imported ontology if that ontology is already loaded, but it will not load a new ontology when the import is added.

I think this is a bug - there should at least be an option to load ontologies used in imports at the time the import is created. I'll add an issue for this.

Updates will be available [here](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/issues/55).